# Elastic Beanstalk conditional container_commands not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have two Elastic Beanstalk servers for the same code base. One is production and one is staging.

I am trying to user a conditional `container_command` to create a crontab that will only run in production. These conditional statements work fine for regular `commands` but seem to **always** evaluate to true for `container_commands`. However, according to other SO posts and examples, they should work the same for both types of commands.

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
container_commands:
  01_activate_cronjob:
    test: '[ "${BEANSTALK_ENVIRONMENT}" == "production" ]'
    command: "cat .ebextensions/my_cron_file > /etc/cron.d/my_cron_file && chmod 644 /etc/cron.d/my_cron_file"
    leader_only: true
```

`BEANSTALK_ENVIRONMENT` is an Elastic Beanstalk variable set in my beanstalk configurations and I've confirmed that `echo $BEANSTALK_ENVIRONMENT` outputs "production" and "staging" respectively.

I have also tried this `test` line:

```
test: test $BEANSTALK_ENVIRONMENT == production
```

Furthermore, I have verified the correctness of these test commands in the terminal.

```
test $BEANSTALK_ENVIRONMENT == production && echo yes || echo no
# outputs "yes" on the production server and "no" on the staging server
```

I know I could hack/fix this by inserting the conditional statement inside the `command` portion; however, as I said earlier, everything online indicates this should work so I am stumped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#linux-container-commands) you can only use *one* of `test` and `leader_only`, and if you use both, `leader_only` will win:

> A command can be leader-only or have a test, but not both (leader_only takes precedence).

I would re-consider if you definitely need `leader_only` in your particular use-case.

Comment: Wow, good find, you're right. I don't necessarily need `leader_only` right now so I can remove it but I'll keep this mind.